# Is it possible to create a universally accessible symbolic link (symlink) in Mac?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, symlink

As the title states, the question is that normally we can create a symlink via the following command:

> ln -s target_path link_path

But I wonder if you can create a symlinc, therefore no matter where you are, you can always `cd` to this directory.

E.g.

`~ user$ cd repos` will result in `repos user$ _`

`xyz user$ cd repos` will also result in `repos user$ _`

and `repo`'s absolute directory is `~/Desktop/repos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a variable in your profile like this:

```
repos=~/Desktop/repos
```

Then just use `$repos` in your scripts and in Terminal

```
cd $repos
```